# How to find the second highest number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to find the second highest number in an Array

Comment: No home-works buddy, what have you tried yet?

Comment: you find the highest number, then you find the number that's the highest but less than the number you just found.. unless array has < 3 items. O(2n).

Comment: Its not good idea to close it 'cause in our project we required many times this feature to include.

Comment: I found this(http://www.ajaybadgujar.com/finding-second-largest-number-from-array-in-javascript/) solution very useful  with minimal complexity

Comment: Look at the link- `https://stackoverflow.com/a/57360512/8958729`

Answer (score 3):

```
function getSecondHighest(arrCheck){
    var first=0,second=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arrCheck.length;i++){
        if(arrCheck[i] > first){
            second = first;
            first = arrCheck[i];
        }
        else if(arrCheck[i]>second && arrCheck[i]<first){
            second = arrCheck[i];
       } 
    }
    return second;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the first element in the array is the highest number. e.g. [5,4,3,2,1] will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you run through list once; you will find highest number.
Now repeat this one more time and you will get 2nd highest number.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var big = a[0];
    var secondLargest = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] > big) {
            secondLargest = big;
            big = a[i];
        } else if (a[i] > secondLargest) {
            secondLargest = a[i];
        }
    }
    return secondLargest;
}
```

Comment: This will not work if the first element in the array is the highest number. e.g. [5,4,3,2,1] will return 5.

Comment: Just updated the logic of existing one. Please let me know if i missed any edge case.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
var array = [267, 306, 108, 50, 909, 200];
var newCopy = [0];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newCopy[i] = array[i];
}
var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, newCopy);
newCopy.splice(newCopy.indexOf(largest), 1);
largest = Math.max.apply(Math, newCopy);
alert(largest);​
```