# Find the second largest number in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, max

I have an array of three element like [31,23,12] and I want to find the second largest element and its related position **without rearranging the array**.

**Example :**

```
array = [21,23,34]
```

> Second_largest = 23;
>
> Position is = 1;

Comment: i have tried sorting array but after sorting array i can't find the index of element for previous array

Comment: Did you mean second largest element?

Comment: You might try copying the array, sorting, getting the second element, then using *indexOf* to find it in the original. There are other methods also that don't require a copy.

Comment: Yes, but when i sort the array all array present in the function changes.

Comment: @sachinyadav—if you sort a copy, that will not affect the original. But there are other methods too, just that they are likely slower.

Comment: @RobG is affecting the original one.

Comment: @sachinyadav—show your code. `arr2 = arr1` is not a copy (if that's what you're doing).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kjgvnt65/

Comment: @sachinyadav—please post your code here, links rot.

Comment: Seems like you might have to loop through the array twice? Find the largest number the first time, then find the second  largest in the next pass?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kjgvnt65/1/ this is the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the second largest element from an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039770/how-do-i-get-the-second-largest-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Follow the link-
`https://stackoverflow.com/a/57360512/8958729`

Answer (score 6):

Make a clone of your original array using `.slice(0)` like :

```
var temp_arr = arr.slice(0);
```

Then sor it so you get the second largest value at the index `temp_arr.length - 2` of your array :

```
temp_arr.sort()[temp_arr.length - 2]
```

Now you could use `indexOf()` function to get the index of this value retrieved like :

```
arr.indexOf(second_largest_value);
```

```js
var arr = [23, 21, 34, 34];
var temp_arr = [...new Set(arr)].slice(0); //clone array
var second_largest_value = temp_arr.sort()[temp_arr.length - 2];
var index_of_largest_value = arr.indexOf(second_largest_value);

console.log(second_largest_value);
console.log(index_of_largest_value);
```

Comment: if arr array has two highest numbers, ie 34, 34, this doesn't work, we can't find the second highest

Answer (score 4):

I tried to make the answer as simple as possible here, you can it **super simple**

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    var flarge = 0;
    var slarge = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) { 
            if (flarge < nums[i]) {
                slarge = flarge;
                flarge = nums[i];
            } else if (nums[i] > slarge) { 
                slarge = nums[i]

            }
        }
        return slarge; 
}
```

Its fully logical ,there is no array sort or reverse here, you can also **use this when values are duplicate in aray**.

Answer (score 4):

Using ES6 **Set** and **Array.from**

```
const secondLargest = (arr) => Array.from([...new Set(arr)]).sort((a,b) => b-a)[1]
```

Above function removes duplicate elements using **Set** and returns the second largest element from the sorted array.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
nums.sort(function(x,y){
       return y-x;
    });
for(var j=1; j < nums.length; j++)
 {
    if(nums[j-1] !== nums[j])
    {
         return nums[j];
    }
 }
}
getSecondLargest([1,2,3,4,5,5]);
```

*OUTPUT:* **4**

*This method will also take care of the multiple occurrence of a number in the array. Here, we are first sorting the array and then ignoring the same number and returning our answer.*

Answer (score 2):

You could create a copy of the original `array` using `spread` and `sort()` it. From you'd just get the second to last number from the array and use `indexOf` to reveal it's index.

```js
const array = [21,23,34];
const arrayCopy = [...array];

const secondLargestNum = arrayCopy.sort()[arrayCopy.length - 2]

console.log(array.indexOf(secondLargestNum));
```

Alternatively you can use `concat` to copy the array if compatibility is an issue:

```js
var array = [21, 23, 34];
var arrayCopy = [].concat(array);

var secondLargestNum = arrayCopy.sort()[arrayCopy.length - 2]

console.log(array.indexOf(secondLargestNum));
```

Comment: Judging by the comments, OP doesn't want to mutate the original array. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Looks like it's not supported natively in IE (shocker) but supported an alternative nonetheless in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This way is the most verbose, but also the most algorithmically efficient. It only requires 1 pass through the original array, does not require copying the array, nor sorting. It is also ES5 compliant, since you were asking about supportability.

```js
var array = [21,23,34];

var res = array.reduce(function (results, curr, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
        results.largest = curr;
        results.secondLargest = curr;
        results.indexOfSecondLargest = 0;
        results.indexOfLargest = 0;
    }
    else if (curr > results.secondLargest && curr <= results.largest) {
        results.secondLargest = curr;
        results.indexOfSecondLargest = index;
    }
    else if (curr > results.largest) {
        results.secondLargest = results.largest;
        results.largest = curr;
        results.indexOfSecondLargest = results.indexOfLargest;
        results.indexOfLargest = index;
    }
    return results;
}, {largest: -Infinity, secondLargest: -Infinity, indexOfLargest: -1, indexOfSecondLargest: -1});

console.log("Second Largest: ", res.secondLargest);
console.log("Index of Second Largest: ", res.indexOfSecondLargest);
```

Comment: @sachinyadav "This way is the most verbose, but also the most algorithmically efficient" First sentence of my post lol

Comment: @sachinyadav That solution iterates through the array 3 times. (`slice`, `sort`, `indexOf`), and does not return both the number as well as the corresponding index.

Comment: Any way you could give a quick description of what the second param of reduce is doing? (The object with values of -Infinity)

Comment: @DanielZuzevich It is the initial value that gets passed in as the first parameter of the reduce callback. You can pass anything you want as an initial value, as it is only relevant for the first iteration. Every subsequent iteration uses the return value of the callback function as the "results" parameter of the previous iteration. I hope that makes sense, it's kinda hard to explain.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this problem, but wasn't allowed to use looping.  I managed to get it working using recursion and since no one else suggested that possibility, I decided to post it here. :-)

```
let input = [29, 75, 12, 89, 103, 65, 100, 78, 115, 102, 55, 214]

const secondLargest = (arr, first = -Infinity, second = -Infinity, firstPos = -1, secondPos = -1, idx = 0) => {
    arr = first === -Infinity ? [...arr] : arr;

    const el = arr.shift();
    if (!el) return { second, secondPos }

    if (el > first) {
        second = first;
        secondPos = firstPos;
        first = el;
        firstPos = idx;
    } if (el < first && el > second) {
        second = el;
        secondPos = idx;
    }  

    return secondLargest(arr, first, second, firstPos, secondPos, ++idx);
}

console.log(secondLargest(input));
//  {
//    second: 115,
//    secondPos: 8
//  }
```

Hope this helps someone in my shoes some day.

Answer (score 2):

Simple recursive function to find the n-largest number without permutating **any** array:

**EDIT:** Also works in case of multiple equal large numbers.

```js
let array = [11,23,34];

let secondlargest = Max(array, 2);
let index = array.indexOf(secondlargest);

console.log("Number:", secondlargest ,"at position", index);

function Max(arr, nth = 1, max = Infinity) {
  let large = -Infinity;
  for(e of arr) {
    if(e > large && e < max ) {
      large = e;
    } else if (max == large) {
      nth++;
    }
  }
  if(nth==0) return max;
  return Max(arr, nth-1, large);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to get 2nd largest number-

```
arr = [21,23,34];
secondLargest = arr.slice(0).sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[1];
```

To get 2nd largest number with index in traditional manner-

```
arr = [20,120,111,215,54,78];
max = -Infinity;
max2 = -Infinity;
indexMax = -Infinity;
index2 = -Infinity;

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(max < arr[i]) {
        index2 = indexMax;
        indexMax = i;
        max2 = max;
        max = arr[i];
    } else if(max2 < arr[i]) {
        index2 = i;
        max2 = arr[i];
    }
}

console.log(`index: ${index2} and max2: ${max2}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to solve ***without using the inbuilt function***.

```
var arr = [1,2, -3, 15, 77, 12, 55];
var highest = 0, secondHighest = 0;
// OR var highest = arr[0], secondHighest = arr[0];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i] > highest){
    secondHighest = highest;
    highest = arr[i]; 
  }

  if(arr[i] < highest && arr[i] > secondHighest){
    secondHighest = arr[i];
  }
}

console.log('>> highest number : ',highest); // 77
console.log('>> secondHighest number : ',secondHighest); // 55
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [21,23,34];
var output = getSecondLargest(arr);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;

function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0){
         return undefined;
    }
    nums.sort((a,b) => b-a);
    var newArr = [...new Set(nums)];
    return newArr[1];
}
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  const sortedArray = new Set(nums.sort((a, b) => b - a)).values();
  sortedArray.next();

  return sortedArray.next().value;
}

console.log(getSecondLargest([1, 2, 4, 4, 3]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Suggest making unique array before checking largest value in the array

    function getSecondLargest(arr) {
        let uniqueChars = [...new Set(arr)];
       
        let val=Math.max(...uniqueChars);
       
        let arr1 = arr.filter(function(item) {
        return item !== val;
        })
    
        let num=Math.max(...arr1);
        return num;
    }
    
     function main() {
         const n = +(readLine());
         const nums = readLine().split(' ').map(Number);
        
         console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the code will give the second largest number and the index of it

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 15]

a.sort((a,b)=>a-b) //sorted small to large
const max = Math.max(...a)
const index = a.indexOf(max)
const s = {secondLargest:a[index-1],index:index-1}
console.log(s)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = [21,23,34]

var largest = -Infinity

// Find largest 
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i] > largest) largest = elements[i]
}

var second_largest = -Infinity
var second_largest_position = -1

// Find second largest
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i] > second_largest && elements[i] < largest) {
    second_largest = elements[i]
    second_largest_position = i
  }
}

console.log(second_largest, second_largest_position)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  let arr = nums.slice();//create a copy of the input array
  let max = Math.max(...arr);//find the maximum element
  let occ = 0;
    for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == max)
        {
            occ = occ +1;//count the occurrences of maximum element
        }
    }

    let sortedArr =arr.sort(function(x, y) { return x > y; } );//sort the array

    for(var i = 1 ; i <= occ ; i++){
        sortedArr.pop()//remove the maximum elements from the sorted array
    }


    return Math.max(...sortedArr);//now find the largest to get the second largest



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using `.sort()` and `new Set()`

```
const array = [21, 23, 34, 34];

function getSecondLargest(arr){ 
   return list = [...new Set(arr)].sort((a, b) => b - a)[1]
};

getSecondLargest(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I write the most simple function with **O(n)** complexity using two variables *max* and *secondMax* with simple swapping logic.

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  let max = 0, secondMax = 0;
  nums.forEach((num) => {
    if (num > max) {
        secondMax = max;
        max = num;
    } else if (num != max && num > secondMax) secondMax = num;
  });
  return secondMax;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here you can also deal with if the second largest or largest number is repeated

```
var nums =[2,3,6,6,5]; 
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    let secondlargets;
nums.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
// all elements are in the accesindg order
// [1,2,3,5,6,6]
var highest;
// that is the last sorted element
highest = nums[nums.length-1];

nums.pop();
// through above statment we are removing the highest element 
for(let i =0;i<nums.length-1;i++){
  if(nums[nums.length-1]==highest){
    /* here we remove gives this as conditon because might be the hiesht 
     had more indecis as we have in this question index(5) &index(6)
    so remove the element till all positon have elemnt excepts the highest */
     nums.pop()        
 }
else{
    
    return nums[nums.length-1]
/*  our array is already sorted and after removing thew highest element */
        }

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find a simple solution, without using inbuild functions:

### Time complexity is O(n)

```js
function secondLargest(arr) {
        let prev = [0]
        let i =1;
        let largest =0;
        while(i<arr.length){
            let current = arr[i];
            if(current > largest ) {
                largest = current;
                prev = arr[i-1];
            } else if (current > prev && current < largest) {
                prev = current
            }
            i++;
        }
        return prev;
    }
    
    let arr = [1,2,3,41,61,10,3,5,23];
    console.log(secondLargest(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* we can solve it with recursion*/
     let count = 0;    /* when find max then count ++ */
     findSecondMax = (arr)=> {
       let max = 0;  /* when recursive function call again max will reinitialize and we get latest max */
         arr.map((d,i)=>{
            if(d > max) {
                max = d;
            }
            if(i == arr.length -1) count++;
         })
/* when count == 1 then we got out max so remove max from array and call recursively again with rest array so now count will give 2 here we go with 2nd max from array */
       return count == 1 ? findSecondMax(arr.slice(0,arr.indexOf(max)).concat(arr.slice(arr.indexOf(max)+1))) : max;
    }

    console.log(findSecondMax([1,5,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    var a = nums.sort();
    var max = Math.max(...nums);
    var rev = a.reverse();
    for(var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (rev[i] < max) {
            return rev[i];
        }
    }
}
var nums = [2,3,6,6,5];
console.log( getSecondLargest(nums) );
```

Comment: although this might be a correct answer, people give more value to answers witch describe what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

**Find Second Highest Number (Array contains duplicate values)**

```
const getSecondHighestNumber = (numbersArry) =>  {
  let maxNumber = Math.max( ...numbersArry);
  let arrFiltered = numbersArry.filter(val => val != maxNumber);
  return arrFiltered.length ? Math.max(...arrFiltered) : -1;
}
let items = ["6","2","4","5","5","5"];
const secondHighestVal = getSecondHighestNumber(items);
console.log(secondHighestVal); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrData = [21, 23, 34];

const minArrValue = Math.min(...arrData);
const maxArrValue = Math.max(...arrData);

let targetHighValue = minArrValue;
let targetLowValue = maxArrValue;

for (i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
  if (arrData[i] < maxArrValue && arrData[i] > targetHighValue) {
    targetHighValue = arrData[i];
  }
  if (arrData[i] > minArrValue && arrData[i] < targetLowValue) {
    targetLowValue = arrData[i];
  }
}

console.log('Array: [' + arrData + ']');
console.log('Low Value: ' + minArrValue);
console.log('2nd Lowest Value: ' + targetLowValue);
console.log('2nd Highest Value: ' + targetHighValue);
console.log('High Value: ' + maxArrValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if the max number appears multiple times in your array (like [6, 3,5,6,3,2,6]), you won't get the right output. So here is my solution:

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    const sortedNumbers = nums.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    const max = sortedNumbers[0];
    const secondMax = sortedNumbers.find(number => number < max);

    return secondMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const findSecondlargestNumber = (data) => {
    let largest = null;
    let secondlargest = null;

    data.forEach(num => {
        if(!largest) {
            largest = num;
           
        }
        else if(num > largest) {
            secondlargest = largest;
            largest = num;
        }
        else if((!secondlargest && num !== largest) || (secondlargest)) {
            secondlargest = num;
        }
    })

    return secondlargest;
}

console.log(findSecondlargestNumber([11, 11, 3, 5, 6,2, 7]))
```

Comment: This does not always get the second largest number. If you try something like `findSecondlargestNumber([11, 5, 7, 1])` it will return `1` which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if there are repeated numbers then they will be removed, and then will sort the array and find the second-largest number.

```js
let arr=[12,13,42,34,34,21,42,39]
let uniqueArray=[...new Set(arr)]
let sortedArray=uniqueArray.sort((a,b)=>b-a)
console.log(sortedArray[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way to get the second largest number and it's respective position from an array without rearranging the array or without using sorting method.

```js
function findSecondLargest(arr) {
  const largest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  arr[arr.indexOf(largest)] = -Infinity; 
  const secondLargest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  const position = arr.indexOf(secondLargest);
  return { secondLargest, position };
}
console.log(findSecondLargest([3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13])); //{ secondLargest: 11, position: 4 }
```

**-Infinity** is smaller than any negative finite number.

Answer (score -1):

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  const len = nums.length;
  const sort_arr = nums.sort();
  var mynum = nums[len-1];
  for(let i=len; i>0; i--){
    if(mynum>nums[i-1]){
        return nums[i-1]; 
    }
  }
}
```